# How to extract a Rar file with password in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip, rar, unrar

Hi i'm currently using Google Colab and i need a extract a Rar file with password.
I use Patool but it doesn't support Password's file

Comment: Would 7zip be a possibility? You should probably move this question to super user.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This would be better asked on [su]. Please see "[ask]" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
!7z e -pPASSWORD file.rar
```

Comment: While this code may work as a solution, it is better to add context, and explain your code. This helps future visitors hone in on what is important to pay attention to in this code, and helps others learn, so they can apply this knowledge to their own code. Or address how/why this code differs from the OP's attempts and contrast why this solution works. This keeps SO quality high, discourages "give me the code" questions, and encourages sharing *knowledge & information*. Visitors are more likely to pay attention to & read informative posts. High quality Answers are more likely to get "upvotes"